# How to determine if a type implements an interface and use members of that interface

Tags: c#, interface

I am building a `Vector<T>` class and I am having differculties with an `Add` method. What I already have is the interface that makes adding possible, but only if I know that `T` implements `IAddable<TIn, TOut>`.

```
interface IAddable<TIn, TOut>
{
    Vector<TOut> Add(Vector<TIn>)
}

partial Vector<T> where T : IAddable<T, T>
{
    public Vector<T> Add(Vector<T> v)
    {
        return mapIndexed((index, x) => this[index].Add(v[index]));
    }
}
```

The point is, I want to be able to add `Vector<T>` and `Vector<TIn>` to a `Vector<TOut>` for every `T` that implements `IAddable<TIn, TOut>`. My solution below obviously doesn't work because you can't just call `this[index].Add(v[index])`. Is there a way to call it without running into this kind of problems?

```
partial Vector<T>
{
    public Vector<TOut> Add<TIn, TOut>(Vector<TIn> v)
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IAddable<TIn, TOut>)))
            return mapIndexed((index, x) => this[index].Add(v[index]));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your intent is not clear. Do you need vector of vectors or just vector of ints you want to be able to convert to vector of doubles?

Comment: That doesn't answer your question but, what are you atually trying to achieve? Because if you're adding int and double to the same place then generics will brea down and you will end up at the object level anyway so i'm not sure what you're trying to achieve is actually going to help you instead of just pushing the problem one level down

Comment: What I want to archieve is a `Vector<T>` class, and when `T` can be added to a `TIn`, I want that `Vector<T>` can be added to a `Vector<TIn>` without any extra work.

Comment: If i understand you correctly than you need covariance type parameter. You can read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
If T.GetInterface("IAddable<TIn, TOut>") != null { /* Use in vector... */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no need for contrvariance here.
The following will allow to add a `Vector<T>` into `Vector<T2>` only if `T2` is derives from `T`

```
public interface IMyVector<T>
{
    void AddVector<TIn>(IMyVector<TIn> vector) where TIn : T;
}

public class Vector<T> : IMyVector<T>
{
    public void AddVector<TIn>(IMyVector<TIn> vector) where TIn : T
    {
        // Your logic here
    }
}

public class Base {}

public class Derived : Base {}
```

And the test class:

```
public class Tests
{
    public void Test()
    {
        IMyVector<Base> baseVector= null;
        IMyVector<Derived> derivedVector= null;

        baseVector.AddVector(derivedVector);
    }
}
```